# RSpec doesn't automatically determine view spec type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3

I have a view located at `app/views/shared/_card_instance.html.haml`. The following spec passes:

**spec/views/_card_instance.html.haml_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'card_instance partial', type: :view do
  it 'should just display the missing slot if present' do
    card = double(:card, missing_slot: 'Rare')
    render 'shared/card_instance', card: card

    expect(rendered).to have_css('.card', text: 'Rare')
  end
end
```

However, if I drop the `type: :view`, it fails:

```
Failures:

  1) card_instance partial should just display the missing slot if present
     Failure/Error: render 'shared/card_instance', card: card
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `render' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::CardInstancePartial:0x5d02b50>
     # ./spec/views/_card_instance.html.haml_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why? Shouldn't RSpec be identifying the spec as a view spec based on its path?

(RSpec 3.1; Rails 3.2; Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this behavior was changed:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#file-type-inference-disabled

Comment: Aha! That also explains the problems I had getting a helper spec to work. Thanks!